# How Does WinAPI ensure compilation fail when WinMain is not implemented

Tags: c++, winapi

When you create a Win32 Project in Visual Studio and dont define a `WinMain` function you get the compilation error:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

How is this API setup designed/implemented to ensure the user can never create a Win32 application without implementing a `WinMain`? I am creating an API and I also want to put in compilation errors when the user hasn't used the API properly or hasn't implemented essential features.

An example of where I want to use something similar is: the user must implement an `App` class (base or inherited). So if I can somehow detect at compilation time that the `App` class has not been implemented I can also throw a compilation error.

Is WinAPI's implementation as simple as a forward declaration function that hasn't been implemented (which ensures compilation failure)? Ie,

```
// Forward declaration with, intentionally, no function implementation
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE  hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE  hPrevInstance, _In_ LPTSTR  lpCmdLine, _In_ int  nCmdShow);
```

Comment: It won't be a compile error, it will be a link error

Comment: The entrypoint of a program is a function inside the C runtime library, __tmainCRTStartup in your case.  It takes care of initialization.  And then calls WinMain().  Since your program does not have one, you get a plain linker error.  A common mistake is to target the wrong sub-system, /SUBSYSTEM linker option.  You selected WINDOWS, then the expected program entrypoint is WinMain().  But it is pretty common to write console mode apps in c++, subsystem CONSOLE, then you need the standard main().

Comment: You cannot detect this at compile-time. However, you can detect a missing *App* implementation at link-time. And you don't have to do anything special, either. Just declare an *App* object (`extern CApp App;`) and use it. The linker will take care of the rest. This doesn't produce very helpful error messages, and you'll need to document this in your library's FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

When starting a program, the OS loads the module and then calls the initialization code. Which symbol carries that initialization code (entrypoint) can be changed, but typically it is something like `winMainCRTStartup` or `mainCRTStartup` (if I remember correctly). Now, that function is supplied by the compiler vendor and linked into your program. It first calls initialization code, e.g. constructors of globals and then delegates to the various forms of `main()` or `winMain()`. Here also lies the reason why compilation fails: Since the initialization code is always included (via its externally visible entrypoint) and it always calls the according main function, a missing main function will cause a linker error.

Note that a simple declaration is not enough (you could have tried that), you must ensure that the function it declares is actually used.

Concerning your approach to generate errors, I don't think it's feasible, at least not at compile-time. If possible, I would also try to avoid such rigid constraints for using a library. Why shouldn't there be multiple such classes or multiple uses for your library inside your application? If the constraint really makes sense, consider using a technique like many windowing libraries that provide a global function that registers the user-written instance. You can then add according checks to your code that `assert()` that the instance was registered.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So to put it simply, the compiler (MinGW presumably) is what prevents the compilation and nothing (or not much) in the WinAPI library code? And this is because the compiler is looking for a specific symbol (for the initialisation code).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is indeed about as simple as you expect it to be. In your code, derive from `App` and the compiler will complain if that base is not supplied.

You *will* have to ship source code for this: you can't get a compiler error without having compiler input, and the input to a compiler is source code. Having said that, it doesn't mean you have to ship all your code as source. You might ship a header that has `class Derived : public App { ... }` but whose methods are just (inlined) calls to your .LIB.